# Why am I getting the error 'Type 'PublicTableViewController' has no member 'handleRefresh''

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to implement pull to reload for my `UITableViewController` in swift here is my code:

```swift
class PublicTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PublicTableViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    }

    func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    ...
}
```

But when I build this I get the error that Type 'PublicTableViewController' has no member 'handleRefresh'' and I do not understand why.

Comment: You need to annotate it with @objc to use it with #selector, `@objc func handleRefresh...`

Comment: As mentioned don’t forget to match the parameter but do you really need a parameter since you don’t seem to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change like this.

```
class PublicTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleRefresh()), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    }

   @objc func handleRefresh() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

you must add @objc to a method sing to adopt #selector.

Comment: I added that and got the same result

Comment: try without params

Answer (score 3):

The function signature specified in the selector is not the same as your actual function.

Either, change your function to this:

```
@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and keep your selector as is.

Or change your selector to this:

```
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PublicTableViewController.handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

and keep your function as is.

*Tip*: When you write the selector and you hit the dot after `PublicTableViewController`, Xcode will auto suggest the correct function signature ;)